# PHP seperate URLs in array but not the last one

Tags: php

I want to organize my URLS so they are like this

```
url1.com
:url2.com
:url3.com
```

How can i check if its the last entry in the array to make sure it dosen't put a new line and a : after the last URL ?

```
foreach($urls as $url) {
        $splits .= "$url\n:";
    }
```

Comment: `$splits = implode("\n:", $urls)`

Comment: the `implode` function is the best solution. If for some reason you didn't want to use it, you could go for a `for` loop and check if the counter variable is at the upper bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$string = implode(PHP_EOL.':', $urls);`

You should use the PHP_EOL constant so you are not depending on a specific OS.

Comment: Thanks, completely forgot about using implode

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is as easy as mentioned then you can use the `implode` method (as others solutions show). For more complex constructs you may want to use something simmilar to this:

```
foreach ($urls as $url) {

  if (!end($urls) === $url) {

    // the n-th element
    // ...

  }

  // the last element
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I would make it !end() though, because he described wanting to do something every time BUT the end. Otherwise, yes, for more complicated things.